# Построение поля для кроссворда

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не могу придумать алгоритм. У нас есть список слов, не важно какой длины. Необходимо построить поле для кроссворда при участии данных слов. Данная задача есть в книге "Этюды программирования".

На данный момент мои рассуждения такие:

1. отсортировать слова по количеству букв
2. представить данное поле как двумерный *char*-массив
3. в центр поля поместить самое длинное слово и начать работать от него
4. слова должны читаться строго слева на право и сверху вниз

Как именно вставлять слова, да так чтобы одно слово могло не просто пересекаться с другим, а с несколькими?

UPD

Посмотрел на кроссворды и понял, что количество вертикальных и горизонтальных слов всегда пропорционально, плюс/минус одно-два. Значит, необходимо реализовать две функции - одну для горизонтальных, другую для вертикальных. И вызывать их друг за другом через рекурсию пока не будут использованы все слова.

UPD 
(прошу прощения за качество изображения, рисовал в гимпе быстро)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо ввести такое понятие как красная зона, чтобы не было "слипания" слов.

UPD

Нашел статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/166471/, прочтение исходного кода ничего не дало.

UPD

Еще одна зацепка найдена. Книга : Мозговой М.В. "C++ Мастер класс 85 нетривиальных проектов, решений и задач". Есть способ реализации построения кроссворда, только он завязан на том что у нас уже дана определенная сетка и достаточной большой список слов, который не будет использоваться весь.

Comment: Я как-то давно искал решение на C#, здесь есть небольшое описание алгоритма http://codingcraft.ru/open_source/crossword/generator.php, там же можно взглянуть на исходник и саму программу

Answer (score 8):

Почитайте эти статьи:

1. «[Алгоритм формирования кроссвордов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/249899/)»,
2. «[Построение кроссвордов с помощью языка Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](http://habrahabr.ru/company/wolfram/blog/249141/)».

Вкратце, составление кроссвордов — нетривиальная задача, требующая большой базы слов. При этом нет никаких гарантий, что все слова получится уложить в сетку.

*Добавлено*. Красная зона легко реализуется добавлением пробелов в начало и конец каждого слова.

Comment: Вторая статья подходит под мои цели. Так как нету у меня необходимости делать сложный блоковый кроссворд. Кстати нашел ответ на еще один вопрос. Сделать "красную зону" чтобы слова не стояли прям таки в одну линию, а между ними был разделитель.

Answer (score 8):

У меня есть некоторая идея алгоритма, но скорее всего она не самая оптимальная.

1. Сортируем базу слов, чтобы самые длинные располагались в начале;
2. Создаем двумерный символьный массив размерностью *N x N*, где *N* можно взять в 1.5 - 2 раза больше, чем самое длинное слово из имеющегося списка;
3. По горизонатли в середину массива помещаем самое длинное слово;
4. Выбираем следующие по длине слово, у которого хоть 1 буква совпадает с первым, и размещаем его в нужном месте по вертикали;
5. Далее реализуем цикл, пока не выберем все слова из нашей базы, или не завершатся возможные позиции для добавления слов:

   - Поочередно выбираем, добавляем ли мы новое слово по вертикали, или
     по горизонтали;
   - Проходим по строкам, или столбцам массива, через 1 (так обеспечим отсутствие "слипания" слов, если добавляем по горизонтали, двигаемся по строкам, иначе - по столбцам), ищем стоки/столбцы, в которых присутствуют обрамленные пустыми ячейками единичные символы, сохраняем эти символы и размер промежутков между ними в элемент некоторого списка,   например, из комбинации строк:

     ```
     .гиппопотам. 
     .  
     .  
     .    
     .пароход.  
     .   
     .комод.
     ```

     Можно было бы составить вот такие элементы списка: `г-3-п-1-к`, `п-3-р-1-м`, `о-3-х-1-д`, `о-3-д`, и т.д. (Как именно формировать такие элементы списка, чтобы их потом было удобно разбирать - отдельный вопрос, можно формировать регулярное выражение, а может даже лучше не переносить сами буквы из массива, а добавлять в список структуру вида

     ```
     {   
         направление(гориз./верт.);   
         количество букв;    
         номер строки начала;   
         номер столбца начала;   
     }
     ```

     И сопоставлять со словами буквы из массива по заданной в этой структуре позиции).
     Список формируем по убыванию количества букв в сформированных элементах.
   - Проходим по базе слов, выбирая поочередно начиная с самых длинных, и сопоставляем с элементами в списке, пока не найдем слово, буквы и их положение в котором совпадают с элементом из сформированного нами на предыдущем шаге списка.
   - Размещаем найденное слово в нужной позиции в массиве, если его размер позволяет и оно не перекрывает какое-то другое слово в той же строке (иначе, продолжаем проход по базе), исключаем его из базы, возвращаемся в начало цикла.
   - Если слов не осталось, или ни одного совпадения не нашлось (даже с 1 буквой) ни при вертикальном добавлении, ни при горизонтальном, значит все что могли мы построили, выходим из цикла.

**UPD:**
Пример для добавления слова, пересекающегося с двумя по вертикали:

```
.........
..г...ф..  
..р...а..  
..а...в..
..ф...н..
```

передвигаясь по строкам через одну, мы можем составить элементы списка р-3-а, ф-3-н для этих двух слов, если мы будем использовать в качестве элемента списка вышеописанную структуру, то для строки номер 3 мы получим :
направление - горизонталь
количество букв - 2
номер строки начала - 2 (если учесть привычный отсчет в массиве с 0)
номер столбца начала - 2

Пройдя по базе, мы обнаружили, что под первый элемент списка подходит слово "трубка", мы знаем смещение первой совпавшей буквы в массиве - (строка 2, столбец 2), значит можем высчитать и положение первой буквы найденного нами слова, и поместить его в массив (строка 2, столбец 1).

Comment: Опять таки, непонятно как делать пересечение допустим с двумя вертикальными словами по горизонтали.

Comment: Почему непонятно? ровно так же, - двигаться через одну по строкам, складывая в элементы списка всевозможные варианты типа "слово содержит букву 'е' и через 3 позиции от нее букву 'д' ", затем в базе слов найти подходящее под один из собарнных в списке вариантов. Обновила ответ.