# Кроссворд на с++

Tags: c++

Студенческая задачка, дословно звучит так: Разработка программы "Кроссворд". Программа автоматически генерирует кросворд по определенной тематике и типу кросворда

Если честно ничего не шарю а это единственный предмет, который тяжело закрыть в универе

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454353/178988

Comment: https://geektimes.com/post/296221/ & https://geektimes.com/post/243643/ & https://habr.com/post/249899/

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос: что и как вы конкретно пытались делать? Продемонстрируйте ваши попытки, иначе, это похоже на то, что мы за вас должны сделать вашу работу.

Comment: тревога -> должен быть закрыт -> непонятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Раз никаких требований в условии нет, то надо делать так, как тебе проще сделать.

Неясно, что такое тип кроссворда. Можно было бы предполагать разные типы (кроссворд, сканворд, соты и т. д.), но  действуем проще и определяем тип кроссворда как внешний вид сетки, в которую надо вписать слова.

Что касается тематики - нужно хранилище со словами, заданиями к ним и тематиками. Можно использовать БД или простой текстовый файл. Учитывая метку си++, я бы выбрал текстовый файл.

Ничего не говорится про необходимость интерфейса для добавления и удаления чего либо (слов, типов, тематик), значит не делаем.

---

И так, пользователь выбирает сетку и тематику. Мы берём все слова и отфильтровываем среди них те, которые подходят под выбранную тематику. Дальше перебором начинаем размещать их в сетке.

Недостаток: для нормальных кроссвордов понадобится очень большой словарь - непонятно, где его взять. Ну или можно продемонстрировать, что программа просто работает на не6ольших сетках.

Не очень уверен в скорости работы, но полагаю, что там всё должно быть хорошо.